# VBA Excel timer(stop watch) time resets after saving, closing and reopening the file

Tags: vba, excel

this is only my second post, I hope I got it right.

I have a workbook with a couple timers (stop watches) which work fine. They stop start and clear with the 'active x' buttons with no issues. The problem is when I close the workbook and reopen. I click the Start button and the time resets to 00:00:00:00 and then goes... this is something I'm using to track actual time spent over a month and really need it not to reset to zero after closing and reopening. Below is my code.. I'm self taught and "borrowed" much of this code online.  Thanks in advance

```
Public StopIt As Boolean
Public ResetIt As Boolean
Public LastTime

Public StopIt2 As Boolean
Public ResetIt2 As Boolean
Public LastTime2


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim StartTime, FinishTime, TotalTime, PauseTime

Me.CommandButton1.Enabled = False
StopIt = False
ResetIt = False
If Range("D5") = 0 Then
  StartTime = ("D5") = Timer
  PauseTime = 0
  LastTime = 0
Else
  StartTime = 0
  PauseTime = Timer
End If
StartIt:
  DoEvents
  If StopIt = True Then
    LastTime = TotalTime
    Exit Sub
  Else
    FinishTime = Timer
    TotalTime = FinishTime - StartTime + LastTime - PauseTime
    TTime = TotalTime * 100
    HM = TTime Mod 100
    TTime = TTime \ 100
    hh = TTime \ 3600
    TTime = TTime Mod 3600
    MM = TTime \ 60
    SS = TTime Mod 60
    Range("D5").Value = Format(hh, "00") & ":" & Format(MM, "00") & ":" & Format(SS, "00") & "." & Format(HM, "00")
    If ResetIt = True Then
      Range("D5") = Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & "." & Format(0, "00")
      LastTime = 0
      PauseTime = 0

      End
    End If
    GoTo StartIt

  End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim StartTime2, FinishTime2, TotalTime2, PauseTime2

    Me.CommandButton4.Enabled = False
StopIt2 = False
ResetIt2 = False
If Range("D8") = 0 Then
  StartTime2 = Timer
  PauseTime2 = 0
  LastTime2 = 0
Else
  StartTime2 = 0
  PauseTime2 = Timer
End If
StartIt2:
  DoEvents
  If StopIt2 = True Then
    LastTime2 = TotalTime2
    Exit Sub
  Else
    FinishTime2 = Timer
    TotalTime2 = FinishTime2 - StartTime2 + LastTime2 - PauseTime2
    TTime = TotalTime2 * 100
    HM = TTime Mod 100
    TTime = TTime \ 100
    hh = TTime \ 3600
    TTime = TTime Mod 3600
    MM = TTime \ 60
    SS = TTime Mod 60
    Range("D8").Value = Format(hh, "00") & ":" & Format(MM, "00") & ":" & Format(SS, "00") & "." & Format(HM, "00")
    If ResetIt2 = True Then
      Range("D8") = Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & "." & Format(0, "00")
      LastTime2 = 0
      PauseTime2 = 0
      End
    End If
    GoTo StartIt2
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
  Me.CommandButton1.Enabled = True
  StopIt = True
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton5_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Me.CommandButton4.Enabled = True
    StopIt2 = True
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
  Dim Msg As String, Ans As Variant

    Msg = "Are you sure you want to reset ALL timers .. Did you send your monthly report?"

    Ans = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo)

    Select Case Ans

    Case vbYes
  Range("D5").Value = Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & "." & Format(0, "00")
  LastTime = 0
  Range("D8").Value = Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & ":" & Format(0, "00") & "." & Format(0, "00")
  LastTime2 = 0
  ResetIt = True

  Case vbNo
GoTo Quit:
    End Select

Quit:
End Sub
```

Comment: You're going to need to save the current time somewhere in the workbook, like as a NAME (google it) when the workbook is closed, and then you reload your "timer" from the name when you start back up.

Comment: You will want to save the values to something like an INI file (which is just a fancy text file) - But honestly, you really should be using a database for something like this. Do you have Microsoft Access as well?

Comment: I have Access but unfortunately zero experience using it.

Comment: As @hoodaticus suggests, store the times in Names, or even just on a hidden worksheet.  That's all you need.

Comment: To do you one even better, you could put a table on a hidden worksheet and add a 'record' every time the workbook is closed. That way you could not only store the total time spent, but the individual times spent (especially if there's the risk of someone not closing the workbook when they finish, and thus completely corrupting the end result).

Comment: So, I already have the times backing up in a another sheet using =Sheet1!D5.  I tried to have it start the time from there by adding this to my code but it failed   StartTime = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b2") = Timer.  Sorry like I said self taught and today it's really showing

Answer (score 0):

use custom property to store persistent data

the first part stores data in sheet property, so you could keep track of each worksheet separately, if you wanted

the second part stores data in workbook property
workbook custom properties are also set in "File tab" under "Properties"

```
Sub customProperties()

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").customProperties.Add "abc123", 123
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").customProperties(1)     ' custom properties are not indexed by name

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").customProperties(1).Value = "this is my data"
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").customProperties(1)

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").customProperties(1).Delete


    ' CustomDocumentProperties Types
    ' msoPropertyTypeBoolean  2
    ' msoPropertyTypeDate     3
    ' msoPropertyTypeFloat    5
    ' msoPropertyTypeNumber   1
    ' msoPropertyTypeString   4


    ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="xyz", LinkToContent:=False, Type:=msoPropertyTypeString, Value:="xyz"
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("xyz")

    ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("xyz").Value = "abcdefg"
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("xyz")

    ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("xyz").Delete




End Sub
```